# In Rails 2.x, what is the difference between "rake gems:unpack" and "rake gems:freeze"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

It seems that both methods can freeze a gem into the `vendor` directory, but `rake gems:unpack` requires the gem to be listed
in `config/environment.rb` as `config.gem '<name of the gem>'` before the `rake` is done.

On the other hand, `rake gems:freeze` requires installing the gem `gemsonrails` first, and uses the syntax `rake gems:freeze GEM=haml` and it 
doesn't require listing the gem in `environment.rb` first.  But it doesn't work with the current GEM class (probably requires gem 1.3.6 instead of 1.3.7).

Besides these, what are the differences between them?  Do they work very similarly and achieve the same purpose?  `gemsonrails`'s webpage wasn't updated since 2007; is `rake gems:unpack` the
more preferred way of freezing a gem if not using Bundler?

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrangling with config.gem and unpacked gems for a long time, but never actually used rake gems:freeze.

The reason being that I never tried to get all gems unpacked/frozen (which I believe is the same thing), only those that caused problems during the rake gems:install process by introducing circular dependencies together with the environment.

So I can't completely answer your question - but I would advise to switch to bundler. I've used it with Rails 2.3.1, and never looked back to the gems:install system (bundler has or had some problems as well, but never on same nightmarish level).